# why doesn't Material Table sorting nor paginationt work?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I managed with some support to feed data from a rest api call into a Materialdata table. Unfortunately the pagination nor sorting does work. My assumnption is that the initilization is somehow wrong. 
when loading the page I'm getting a ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in the console. After 1-2 seconds I see the rest response and the data is shown in the table but wether sorting nor pagination is working. When clicking on table headers to sort the data there is no additional error.

accountlist-datasource.ts

```
import { Account } from './../_services/accounts';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

export class AccountlistDataSource extends DataSource<Account> {
data: Account[];

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Account[]> {
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    this.paginator.length = this.data.length;

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  disconnect() {}

  private getPagedData(data: Account[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  private getSortedData(data: Account[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'Name': return compare(a.Name, b.Name, isAsc);
        case 'ID': return compare(+a.ID, +b.ID, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

accountlist.component.html

```
<h1>Institutions / Customer / Accounts</h1>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="accounts.data.Documents" matSort aria-label="Elements">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Account Number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Institution ID</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row['Account Number']}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>SAP Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Country">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Country</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Country}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="State/Province">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>State</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row['State/Province']}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="City">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>City</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.City}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Postal Code">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Postal Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row['Postal Code']}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Address 1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Address</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row['Address 1']}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Created Date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Created Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row['Created Date']}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="accounts.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Accounts.ts

```
export interface Account {
  Name: string;
  ID: string;
  City: string;
  Country: string;
  SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO: string;
  'Account Number': string;
  'Postal Code': string;
  'Address 1': string;
  'Address 2': string;
  'State/Province': string;
}
```

accountslist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { AccountlistDataSource } from './accountlist-datasource';
import { AzureService } from './../_services/azure.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accountlist',
  templateUrl: './accountlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accountlist.component.css']
})
export class AccountlistComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: AccountlistDataSource | null;
  displayedColumns = [
    'Name', 'Account Number', 'SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO', 'Country', 'State/Province', 'City', 'Postal Code', 'Address 1', 'Created Date'];

  public accounts: any;
  isLoading = true;

  constructor(private azureService: AzureService) {
  }

  RenderDataTable() {
    this.azureService.getAccountsAzure()
      .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.accounts = new AccountlistDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
        this.accounts.data = res as Account[];
        console.log(this.accounts);
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('There was an error while retrieving data !!!' + error);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.RenderDataTable();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm not sure what exactly is happening in your code because I can't see a MatTableDataSource initialization, while it is absolutely necessary in order for it to work.
- In order for sorting and paging to work, you must give them a minimal delay since initializing MatTableDataSource takes a bit of time in the background
- This means that MatTableDataSource must be fully-initialized when assigning sort and paginator in order for them to work properly.

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }, 1)
  }
  ```

Comment: inside the accountslist.component.ts - RenderDataTable function?

Comment: I changed the code:

  ngOnInit() {
   this.RenderDataTable();
   setTimeout(function() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }, 2);
  }

but it does not work...

ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined
    at accountlist.component.ts:41

Comment: Don't copy paste the code, understand it (only 2 lines - fairly simple), and apply the it to your code, but you need to adjust it to your code - dataSource name should be different.
It is best if you look at an example here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndjvyykgoje?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts